# Schema level sequences in HSQL

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hsqldb

I am using HSQLDB as a database in my automated component tests. It mocks production's Oracle database.

In my SQL code I have a sequence defined within a schema scope e.g.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE THE_SCHEMA.THE_SEQUENCE ... ;
```

Then when I take nextval from this schema:

```
Connection con = ...
String query = "SELECT THE_SCHEMA.THE_SEQUENCE.nextval as MyNextVal from DUAL;"
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
ResultSet resultSet = ps.executeQuery();
```

I am getting error as below on con.prepareStatement(query) call.

The above code runs well when I define the sequence in the global scope like below

```
CREATE SEQUENCE THE_SEQUENCE ... ;
```

and change

```
String query = "SELECT THE_SEQUENCE.nextval as MyNextVal from DUAL;"
```

**My question is does HSQL support schema level sequences?**

Am I missing something?

(I have "Oracle compatibility mode" turned on with SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX ORA TRUE;)

Stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hsqldb.RangeVariable.resolvesSchemaName(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.RangeVariable.resolvesSchemaAndTableName(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.RangeVariable.findColumn(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ExpressionColumn.resolveColumnReference(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ExpressionColumn.resolveColumnReferences(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.QuerySpecification.resolveColumnReferencesAndAllocate(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.QuerySpecification.resolveColumnReferences(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.QuerySpecification.resolveReferences(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.QueryExpression.resolve(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.compileCursorSpecification(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.StatementManager.compile(Unknown Source)
... 26 more
java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.NullPointerException java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
```

Details on exception that's being thrown from con.prepareStatement(query):

```
Exception type java.sql.SQLException
cause = org.hsqldb.HsqlException: java.lang.NullPointerException
detailMessage = java.lang.NullPointerException java.lang.NullPointerException
next = null
SQLState = S1000
stackTrace = null
vendorCode = -458
```

Comment: What is the reported error?

Comment: Just updated my question with the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please get the latest HSQLDB snapshot jar from http://hsqldb.org/support/ and check if the problem has been fixed.

Comment: That should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: The problem does not occur in snapshot version hsqldb-20131025.144341-55. Thanks!